# Iterate multidimensional JSONObject and get a specific value of inner object

Tags: java, android

I hope you can help me with something that is driving me crazy

I have this simple Json here:

```
    {"2":{"picture":"0","id":52,"bought_date":"2014-08-01","mileage":0,"bike_id":21861,"hours":0,"name":"YZ450F","pictures":"","year":2013,"user_id":34,"cost":8000},"1":{"picture":"140","id":51,"bought_date":"2014-07-28","mileage":0,"bike_id":21130,"hours":0,"name":"Yamaha WR450F 2013","pictures":"","year":2013,"user_id":34,"cost":0},"0":{"picture":"0","id":53,"bought_date":"2014-08-01","mileage":0,"bike_id":18310,"hours":0,"name":"MX 300","pictures":"","year":2011,"user_id":34,"cost":0}}
```

I'm sending this JSONObject to Display_Bikes() which should iterate each element of the JSONObject and then pick every id value in order to fire another method

in pseudo code it would look like this

```
foreach Json as bike{

    get bike.id then
        call anothermethod(bike.id)

}
```

In the reality I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, it's my fourth day with Java so it's understandable, but I'm really frustrated

this is the childish method I'm working on, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
public static void Display_Bikes(JSONObject Bikes){
    Log.v("Bikes", Bikes.toString());
    Iterator<String> iter = Bikes.keys();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String key = iter.next();
        try {
            Object Bike = Bikes.get(key).toString();
            Log.v("Bike", Bike.toString());
            //Now, how to get Bike.id?
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            //error
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Simple json]

Comment: whats the problem exactly?

Comment: I can't get the Bike id value

Comment: that doesnt seem the proper JSON syntax of an array. you would have sth like this [{"id":2,...}, {"id":2,...}] for an array right?

Comment: Yes, that is why I am using JSONObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getJSONObject(String key)`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject(java.lang.String)) to get inner objects:

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    try {
        JSONObject bike = Bikes.getJSONObject(key);
        Log.v("Bike", bike.toString());
        int id = bike.getInt("id");
    } catch(JSONException e) {}

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was so close to this today, now I see where I was mistaking. thanks again and virtual beer